# Same POST works manually, results in 500 error via Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

In my script, I'm using a JSESSIONID instead of a cookie; the JSESSIONID is extracted using a HTTP URL Re-writing Modifier and I can confirm that the correct value (the one which appears in the response data from the login page) is being applied in the Request. 
e.g. POST https://qa67.ososinfo.org:446/Staff/staffdetail.xhtml;JSESSIONID=0655ca5420354753ae413984d34cfc27

I'm also using a VIEWSTATE, which I'm extracting prior to running the remainder of the test steps by using a Regular Expression Extractor and setting the resulting variable as a parameter in the HTTP Request, 
e.g. javax.faces.ViewState=8d2%2BgOIseczB2FWSo74DqQfkmiYVaK73D8bnLTNWCx%2FB8EtE

The problem is that I'm hitting a Response code: 500 | Response message: Internal Server Error every time I attempt a post with all of the applicable data.

I tried running through the steps manually in a Firefox browser. I copied the contents of the Request tab from the failing page into a REST client, logged in using a separate tab of the same browser and grabbed the appropriate JSESSIONID and VIEWSTATE information, then posted with that info in place - and the manual post was successful.

Am I missing something? Is JMeter requiring something to accomplish this POST that a I'm not seeing in a manual attempt? Please note that I can verify the test is working through the point of login - I can manually see the jmeter user logged in from an admin screen.

Happy to share any/all of what I'm seeing if it might be helpful in helping to troubleshoot.

Comment: Are you inspecting the request/response in the 'View Results Tree'.  Perhaps post some of the details of your request.

Comment: please share the  screenshot that shows how you are building. You can debug your script using the combination of View Results Tree and Debug Sampler to know the captured values (ViewStae or JSessionID). I suspect the issue is in encoding. check/uncheck the encoding checkboxes in the Parameters tab against ViewState & JSessionID.  Did you try recording the scenario and correlate and then replay?

Comment: Do you have http cookie manager defined?